# How to redeem a wasted youth?

Tags: destiny

I wasted my youth. I am 35 years old. I had a toxic relationship with my parents, especially my mother. My career never started and am still looking for a fresh start and finding it humiliating at my age.

What does Hinduism says about wasting your youth? Is redemption possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Redemption is absolutely possible. There are several events in puranas that talks about how people wasted a part of their lives in alcohol, sex and so on - and finally had their moment of realization. They went on to become the best leaders or devotees.

Comment: Well how do you define redemption?

Comment: Nothing you've learned & grown from was a waste. It was necessary